# Angular 2/4/5 does not work properly in iOs devices

Tags: ios, angular, angular-material

I have problems with rendering of my webpage in iOs using Angular 2/4/5.

A test page is: [REMOVED, I RESOLVED MY PROBLEM]

This page is displayed properly with all operative systems except iOs, I tried it with Android, Windows, with a lot of different browser and all it's ok, but with my iPhone or with my iPad the list of article is not loaded properly.

This page has this implementation for first article and similar for others:

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="articoli.length > 0">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <app-news-card [articolo]="articoli[0]" [autore]="utenti[0]"></app-news-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

In app-news-card component I have:

```
@Input() articolo:    Articolo;
@Input() autore:      Utente;
```

The news-card is built with Angular Material objects. I honestly don't think the problem is caused by this, in recent past I saw a similar situation caused by using ***ngFor** construct, so I can't understand where and what is the problem with iOs devices.

Somebody can help me?

Comment: Have you added the necessary polyfills for ios?

Comment: I don't understand which polyfills ios needs... I saw this page: https://angular.io/guide/browser-support but I still don't understand, I'm sorry

Comment: I actually have no idea which polyfill ios needs, but perhaps it's not that :) can you try this: `*ngIf="articoli?.length > 0"` (added the safe navigation operator `?`)

Comment: To me is working fine on Safari from my mac, and from the iPad. On chorme, last version, on windows 10 I don't see the pictures. Also the facebook API on the right page is displayed outside the right box on Ios, and I don't see it in chrome

Comment: OMG you solved my problems, it was a polyfills error.
I don't know why, but ios seems to need:

    ALL import 'core-js/es6/XXX';

    import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.
    import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
    import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
    import 'zone.js/dist/zone';

Now it works! I can work to responsivity of my components! Thanks!!